# Alternates to the Neyman-Pearson Lemma?

Tags: probability, statistics

I was reading about the Neyman-Pearson Lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma).

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with unknown parameter $\theta$. Consider two hypotheses:

- Null hypothesis $H_0$: $\theta = \theta_0$
- Alternative hypothesis $H_1$: $\theta = \theta_1$ ( $\theta_1 \neq \theta_0$)

Let $f(x|\theta)$ denote the probability density function (or probability mass function) of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.

The Neyman-Pearson lemma states that the likelihood ratio test (LRT) is the most powerful test at level $\alpha$, where the LRT rejects $H_0$ if and only if:

$$\frac{L(\theta_1 | \mathbf{x})}{L(\theta_0 | \mathbf{x})} > k,$$

where $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is the observed sample, $L(\theta|\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\theta)$ is the likelihood function, and $k$ is a constant chosen such that the test has level $\alpha$.

**My Question:** This might sound like a rhetorical question - but what other possible tests  could exist? The Neyman-Pearson Lemma is said to be very important as it shows us what is the most powerful statistical test - but it seems to me that the test indicated by the Neyman-Pearson is practically the *only* test that exists. What other tests can be considered as competitors?

Thanks!

Comment: Any function that maps $x\in \mathcal{X}^n \mapsto\{\text{accept, reject}\}$ is a test, so a lot of tests exist.

Comment: At any level $\alpha$ any statistic $T(X)$ with $E_{\theta_0}[T(X)]\leq \alpha$ is a valid test. It just so happened that if $T_p(X)$ Pearson's then $E_{\theta_1}[T_p(X)]\geq E_{\theta_1}[T(X)]$.

Comment: @ user51547: thank you for your reply! For argument sake - could you please give me an example of such a test? Thanks!

Comment: @stats_noob e.g. the test where you always accept the null regardless of the data....not a very good test, but a test nonetheless!

Comment: @stats_noob You could look at $T(X)=\bar X$, and decide to reject the null depending on how close it is to $E_{\theta_1} X$ compared to $E_{\theta_0} X$ (provided these exist and are different).